# PHP script error for apple iOS push notification

Tags: php, ios, push-notification

I have an iOS app, I used apple push notification to send the notification when I write new post in my site, so there is php script has the ssl certificates , when I send the push notification  it's usually deliver but in the error log I got this error:

> [27-Mar-2013 15:30:44] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30
>   seconds exceeded in /home3/basiphon/public_html/Push.php on line 56

The push notification (usually) deliver successfully but I got this error in the error log, and there are sometimes the push notifcation not deliver and I got also this error to another error like this :

> [27-Mar-2013 05:45:04] PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]:
>   SSL: connection timeout in /home3/basiphon/public_html/Push.php on
>   line 56 [27-Mar-2013 05:45:04] PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client()
>   [function.stream-socket-client]:
>   Failed to enable crypto in /home3/basiphon/public_html/Push.php on
>   line 56 [27-Mar-2013 05:45:04] PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client()
>   [function.stream-socket-client]:
>   unable to connect to ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195 (Unknown error)
>   in /home3/basiphon/public_html/Push.php on line 56

Please see the code of my push.php script :

```
 `// Open a connection to the APNS server
```

`` $fp = stream_socket_client(
        $url, $err,
        $errstr, 2, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
    if (!$fp)
        exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

    echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;
    // Build the binary notification
    $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

    // Send it to the server
    $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

    if (!$result)
        echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
    else
    {
        echo 'Message successfully delivered111' . PHP_EOL;
        $query_update="update wp_apns_messages set status='delivered',delivery=NOW() where pid='$pid'";
        $res_update=mysql_query($query_update) or die(mysql_error());
    }

    // Close the connection to the server
    fclose($fp);` ``

Comment: Please post the relevant PHP code here in text form, there's a whole bunch of reasons why a screenshot is a bad idea.

Comment: Ok thanks tom, here the full code of my push.php script ,
I will edit the post and put text of script code

Comment: I should've mentioned, you need to **edit your question** rather than _post a comment_, with the code.

Comment: I edited the question , I can't put the full code but I add the last part of the script .

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same error before when running the PHP script provided by a push notification tutorial on www.raywenderlich.com.

Make sure you aren't running any firewalls interfering with your connection to APNs.

If you are following the aforementioned site's tutorial, make sure you are receiving a response and not an error when running the following in terminal:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 
-cert PushChatCert.pem -key PushChatKey.pem
Enter pass phrase for PushChatKey.pem:
```

Comment: Hi bad thanks for answer, you mean firewalls in my mac ? it's set off already , and I will try this code in my terminal .. but does this will effect to my PushChatCert ?

Comment: is there any error with my script code ? do I need to edit something ?

Comment: Nope! The above terminal code will not affect your PushChatCert; the above code connects to APNs with your cert+key. If it works, you should get a bunch of output back. Otherwise, you'll receive an error. 

Also, could be any network firewall that is interfering with your connection. I believe that is your issue, otherwise it is likely your cert/key.

Comment: I run this code and got error, I updated the question , you can see the error, also today I didn't receive the push notification .

Comment: now I got this error in term nail : -bash: Enter: command not found, so what I put for -cert PushChatCert.pem .. is this production certifcate.pem or development certificate.pem ?

Comment: the push notification delivered now but I got this error in the log : PHP Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in , what does mean ?

Comment: Glad you were able to get past the issue you had before in delivering the notification. Dev/Production is depending on how you configured your provisioning profile / cert, I'm assuming yours should be dev. And with your PHP error, your code must be hanging somewhere

Comment: hi bad, I found the devopment.pem certificate is zero byte, so the push notification some time delivered and some times not delivered , but the production.pem is fine, so I decided to create new development.pem and upload it to server and update the php script, I tested now and the push notification delivered quickly for my devices, that's nice but in the error log  it's continue showing this error : PHP Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in 56 , so I don't know why it's showing this .also I need to try more tomorrow .